# MIME type has to be application/zip

Tags: android, facebook, mime

I am uploading an `.apk` file  to Facebook after zipping it.

But when i upload my zip file to Facebook it says the following message "MIME type has to be application/zip".

I have no idea about it can any one guide me whats this and what i need to do to fulfill the criteria of Facebook.

Secondly do i need to make zip file of my `.apk` or not,and how to compatible mime type to application/zip.